# value is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Take a look at this:

```
if(session.getAttribute("mode")!=null){
    mode = (String)session.getAttribute("mode");
}
```

The first time value for the `mode` is empty so I set the `mode` value to a script variable like this:

```
var mode='<%=mode%>';
```

below is the method in which I call on load of the form, but it says `mode is undefined`

```
bodyOnLoad();
var mode='<%=mode%>';
alert("mode : "+mode);
function bodyOnLoad() {
    if(mode.length < 0){
        alert("mode empty 111111");
        document.getElementById("functiontype").value="view";
        document.getElementById("page").value="1";
        document.forms["frmTempcard"].submit(); 
        return;
    }                       
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i am sorry forgot to mention, it is jsp

Comment: Note that you are calling the function `bodyOnLoad` *before* you set the value of `mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable first. The `mode` is undefined when you call the function `bodyOnLoad`.

```
var mode='<%=mode%>';
bodyOnLoad();
```

Comment: thanks @xdazz it helped but now the form is not getting submitted even when the `mode` becomes empty, am i making any problem here ` if(mode.length < 0)`